# Bind annotation with custom converter

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

Is it possible to Trigger Custom Created Converter with annotation.

1) Annotation Class:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Component
public @interface Currency{

   String sourceType();
   String targetType();
}
```

2)Custom Converter:

```
@Component
public class CurrencyConverter implements Converter<Long, Long>{

    @Override
    public Long convert(Long source) {
        return Long.valueOf(source*2); //any Logic
    }
}
```

3) web MVC Config : Register Converter

```
 @Override
 public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
     registry.addConverter(new CurrencyConverter());
 }
```

I want to invoke my custom Converter for my annotated Class.

Comment: I am also facing the same Issue.